# Symfony - checkbox select ALL

Tags: symfony

I have a multiple select checkbox in SYMFONY, in a form builder, but i want to have a 'select all' that select all the selection of my entity.

I try a lots of solution with jquery, but nothing works.

here's my code Controller

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use AdminBundle\Entity\Equipments;

use AdminBundle\Repository\Metier;



class EquipementsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */



    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {


            //$metiers = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Metier')->getForSearch();


            $form = $this->createFormBuilder()

                    ->add('metier', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AdminBundle:Metier', 'choice_label' => 'name','required' => false, 'expanded' => true,  'placeholder' => 'Tous', 'multiple' => true,
```

and my twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<fieldset><legend><b>Filière</b></legend>
    {{ form_row(form.metier) }}
</fieldset>  

<fieldset><legend><b>Opération</b></legend> 
        {{ form_row(form.operation) }}
</fieldset>  
{{ form(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your twig template to include a checkbox for select all:

```
{{ form.row(form.checkboxes, {'attr': {'class': 'class-name-of-checkboxes'} }) }}

<input type="checkbox" id="select-all" name="select-all" /> Select All
```

Changing `.checkboxes` to your relevant form field for your checkboxes. What the above does is add a class to the input called `class-name-of-checkboxes` (change to something more suitable like `form-checkbox`).

This then adds a checkbox underneath that has no relation to any of the form data, all it does is add a checkbox with an id of `select-all` to allow the user to select all checkboxes at once.

then jQuery:

```
$('#select-all').on('change', function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.class-name-of-checkboxes').attr('checked', 'checked')
    }
})
```

The jQuery then uses `.on('change')` on the `$('#select-all')` checkbox object to run a function, if the checkbox is checked, add an attribute of `checked="checked"` to all inputs with class `.class-name-of-checkboxes`

refs:

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

https://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: I try but it gives me this : Neither the property "checkboxes" nor one of the methods "checkboxes()", "getcheckboxes()"/"ischeckboxes()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in AdminBundle:Advert:equipements-drupal.html.twig at line 171.

Comment: i put the jQuery in a <script>

Comment: what's the best solution ?

Comment: ok - great, so what i need to change ?  (thanks for your help)

Comment: {{ form_row(form.metier, {'attr': {'class': 'class-name-of-checkboxes'} }) }}

Comment: can you explan the process again, sorry... i'm a little bit loosing

Comment: i do all of this, i think we're getting close, the select all appear but whe i click on it, nothing change... i import jquery using this in twig : <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: @oliviertoppin - you should be hosting jquery locally - not calling externally ..

Comment: How to do this in twig ?

Comment: @oliviertoppin you download jquery.. add it to your js folder and call it like that in twig?

Comment: @oliviertoppin just download most recent .

Comment: i try this : {% block javascripts %}
 <script src="jquery.js">
{% endblock %}

Comment: @oliviertoppin please read docs on how to do stuff instead of coming back and commenting .. it states that it goes from the public/ directory, so unless jquery.js lives inside the public/ directory at root level, that won't work

Comment: so, is it possible to have 2 select all for 2 different object ?

Comment: @oliviertoppin glad to help, and, yes just use different class names / ids for select all